# Loading Angular Module at runtime

Tags: angular, webpack, rollupjs

I'm investigating ways to deploy an AnguarlJS mixed with an Angular app in a way that will allow me to load more Angular modules at runtime.

The reason for this is to be able to deploy services that will be available in the same UI without redeploying the main UI.

I know Angular supports async loading of modules, the problem is how to make this ability dynamic?

I know the answer will depend on the packaging tool I'll use, either SystemJS, Webpack or Rollup - I'm open to either one of them as long as I can load the modules at runtime.